# Reformatting a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to take data that is received from form input and, in PHP, change the way it is ordered for use in a template creation module/app.  I need it to be in a multidimensional array for use.

```
//How the array currently looks
    $templateData = [
        0 => 'h',
        1 => 1,
        2 => 2,
        3 => 3,
        4 => 'c-1-3',
        5 => 3,
        6 => 5,
        7 => 'c-2-3',
        8 => 3,
        9 => 'c-3-3',
        10 => 'f',
        11 => 2
    ];

//How the array should look
    $templateData = [
        0 =>[ //header row
            0 => [1,2,3] //column
        ],
        1 =>[ //content row(s)
            0 => [3,5], //column
            1 => [3],
            2 => [0]
        ],
        2 => [ //footer row
            0 => [2] //column
        ]
    ]
```

The 'h' represents the start of the header row of the template and 'c-1-3' represents a the start of a row with 3 columns starting with the first column.  The 'f' represents the start of the footer row.  I'm just drawing a blank right now and I can't wrap my head around it.

Here is where I'm at right now, but it's still not working as intended:

```
$elements = $request->input('elements'); //laravel code that grabs array input
    $row = 0;
    $column = 0;
    foreach($elements as $key => $element) {
        //if value is a letter
        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]/', $element)) {
            //if the 3rd letter in the string is a 1
            if(!isset($element[2]) || $element[2] == '1') { $row++; }
            //cycle through values after current key
            for($i=$key+1; $i < count($elements);$i++){
                //until you hit another letter
                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]/', $elements[$i])) { break; }
                $column++;
                $temp[$row][$column][] = $elements[$i];
            }
            $column = 0;
        }
    }
```

The $templateData and $elements variables are the same in the the above and below context.

Comment: what did you tried sofar?

Comment: How you take this -  `2 => [0]` ?

Comment: If 'c-3-3' doesn't exist I still have to set a placeholder of '0'.

Comment: So you always have a minimum of 3 columns ? Which you fill with a placeholder, if they don't exist?

Comment: The input array will contain more than just 1 content rows (header, content, footer) and can be 1 of 'c-1-1', 'c-1-2', or 'c-1-3'.  Just to give you more of an idea on how this is working, the value of each column is referencing an id of a table row (table named 'elements').  If none of these elements were added to the column, I set the value to '0' to show that there are no id's matching in the table.

Comment: I adjusted the example array to be more correct with what the input actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up with.  Finally got it. This works:

```
    //grab input
    $elements = $request->input('elements');

    //initiate row/column numbers
    $row = 0;
    $column = 0;
    $templateData = array();

    //loop through each array value
    foreach($elements as $key => $element) {

        //if value starts with a letter
        if(preg_match('/^[a-z]/', $element)){

            //set total columns
            if($element != 'h' && $element != 'f')
            {
                $totalColumns = substr($element, 4);
            } else {
                $column = 1;
                $totalColumns = 1;
            }

            //if h, c-1-*, or f is detected advance the row
            if(substr($elements[$key], 0) == 'h' || substr($elements[$key], 2) == 1 || substr($elements[$key], 0) == 'f')
            {
                $row++;
            }

            //loop through keys following first recognized letter until you hit another letter
            for($i = $key+1; $i < count($elements) && !preg_match('/^[a-z]/',$elements[$i]); $i++)
            {
                //add element id to column
                $templateData[$row-1][$column-1][] = $elements[$i];
            }

            //if first value in column is not set, add a 0 value to column
            if(!isset($templateData[$row-1][$column-1][0]))
            {
                $templateData[$row-1][$column-1][0] = 0;
            }

            //if its the last column in the set, set to 0
            if($column == $totalColumns)
            {
                $column = 0;
            }

            $column++;
        }
    }
    dd($templateData);
```

Comment: ...this doesn't always work for empty columns though :(  Still working it.

Comment: I've edited the answer so that it now handles empty columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit overkill but you can have full power, and you just need to change the handlers if you want to change the logic. Hope it can help somehow.

```
$templateData = [
    0 => 'h',
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 3,
    4 => 'c-1-3',
    5 => 3,
    6 => 5,
    7 => 'c-2-3',
    8 => 3,
    9 => 'f',
    10 => 2
];

$tmpKey = '';
$tmpArray = [];

class Test
{
    /**
     * @var []
     */
    private $data = [];

    /**
     * @var []
     */
    private $columns = [];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $numOfColumns = 0;

    /**
     * @var []
     */
    private $header = [];

    /**
     * @var []
     */
    private $footer = [];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $current = [
        'key' => '',
        'matches' => ''
    ];

    /**
     * @var []
     */
    private $rules = [
        'header' => [
            'expression' => 'h',
            'handler' => 'headerHandler',
            'matches' => false
        ],
        'footer' => [
            'expression' => 'f',
            'handler' => 'footerHandler',
            'matches' => false
        ],
        'columns' => [
            'expression' => 'c-\d+-\d+',
            'handler' => 'columnHandler',
            'matches' => "columnMatches"
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->process();
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function process()
    {
        foreach($this->data as $data) {

            if (!is_int($data)) {
                if (!$this->setRule($data)) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException("Rule Not found.");
                }
            } else {
                $this->handleRule($data);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    private function headerHandler($data)
    {
        $this->header[] = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    private function footerHandler($data)
    {
        $this->footer[] = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    private function columnHandler($data)
    {
        $columns = explode('-', $this->current['matches']);
        if ($this->columns[($columns[1] - 1)][0] == 0){
            $this->columns[($columns[1] - 1)][0] = $data;
        } else {
            array_push($this->columns[($columns[1] - 1)], $data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    private function columnMatches($data)
    {
        $columns = explode('-', $data);

        if ($this->numOfColumns == 0) {
            $this->numOfColumns = end($columns);
            $this->columns = array_fill(0, $this->numOfColumns, [0]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     * @return bool
     */
    private function setRule($data)
    {
        foreach($this->rules as $key => $rules) {
            if (preg_match("/^{$rules['expression']}$/", $data, $matches)) {
                if ($rules['matches']) {
                    $this->{$rules['matches']}($data);
                }
                $this->current['key'] = $key;
                $this->current['matches'] = $data;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHeader()
    {
        return $this->header;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getColumns()
    {
        return $this->columns;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFooter()
    {
        return $this->footer;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getResult()
    {
        return [
            0 => [$this->header],
            1 => $this->columns,
            2 => $this->footer
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    private function handleRule($data)
    {
        $this->{$this->rules[$this->current['key']]['handler']}($data);
    }

}

$test = new Test($templateData);
echo '<h1>Header</h1>';
var_dump($test->getHeader());
echo '<h1>Footer</h1>';
var_dump($test->getFooter());
echo '<h1>Columns</h1>';
var_dump($test->getColumns());
echo '<h1>Result</h1>';
var_dump($test->getResult());exit;
```

Ideone: [Example Here](https://ideone.com/bwc1b8)

Comment: Yea I would prefer not to instantiate a new class to handle this.  The translation of the array is a response to a POST request.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that, if you don't want to instantiate make it static and call it helper ;)